# How did Planck reach the conclusion that energy comes in packets based on black body curves?

Tags: atomic-structure

I understand that if wavelength continues to decrease energy emitted by an atom would get to infinite, but how does the max wavelength at a particular temperature translate to discrete energy packets. Please explain.

Comment: Planck empirically found an expression that fit the black body radiation curve, particularly for high frequencies. One way to rationalize the form of the expression was that energy emissions had to be discrete.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question seems to be more suitable for SEPhysics.